Error with scaffoldState and drawerContent parameters in Jetpack Compose Scaffold
enter image description here
I am trying to make the navigation pane work of the app I was building using jetpack compose but I am using version material3 for the scaffold and the video through which I am learning is using version1. So, I am not able to figure out how to write the same code in version3.
Here is my MainActivity.kt file
@file:OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

package com.example.littlelemonmainscreen

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter", "SuspiciousIndentation")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState() //First Error. Not able to use    
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState, //Second Error. On LHS side, scaffoldState is turning red and showing error cannot find parameter scaffoldState
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(scaffoldState = scaffoldState, scope = scope) // Fourth Error. Cannot find parameter scaffoldState, scope error
        }
    ) {
        Column {
            UpperPanel()
            LowerPanel()
        }
    }
}


//Here is my DrawerPanel function

@Composable
fun DrawerPanel(scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState? = null, scope: CoroutineScope? = null) {
    List(10) { Text(text = "item $it", modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 10.dp)) }
    IconButton(onClick = {
        scope?.launch { scaffoldState?.drawerState?.open() } //Fifth Error. Not able to use drawerState.open()
    }) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ExitToApp, contentDescription = "Icon Close")
    }
}



Welcome to stackoverflow! I just posted an answer. If you found it useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

Have a look at the material3 Scaffold documentation. There you can see that actually, there is no scaffoldState parameter supported anymore:
@Composable
fun Scaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    bottomBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    snackbarHost: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    floatingActionButtonPosition: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    contentWindowInsets: WindowInsets = ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets,
    content: @Composable (PaddingValues) -> Unit
): Unit

The reason for that is that the drawer state management and the snackbar state management that were previously contained in the scaffoldState are now handled by the Drawer and Snackbar Composables themselves.
Have a look at the ModalNavigationDrawer Composable with the drawerState:
@Composable
fun ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    drawerState: DrawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed),
    gesturesEnabled: Boolean = true,
    scrimColor: Color = DrawerDefaults.scrimColor,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
): Unit

Have a look at the SnackbarHost Composable with the hostState:
@Composable
fun SnackbarHost(
    hostState: SnackbarHostState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    snackbar: @Composable (SnackbarData) -> Unit = { Snackbar(it) }
): Unit

An example containing both the ModalNavigationDrawer and a SnackbarHost would look like this:
val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val items = listOf(Icons.Default.AccountCircle, Icons.Default.Bookmarks, Icons.Default.Dashboard)

val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }

ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet(drawerState) {
            Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(12.dp))
                items.forEach { item ->
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        icon = { Icon(item, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(item.name) },
                        selected = item == selectedItem.value,
                        onClick = {
                            scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                            selectedItem.value = item
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    },
    content = {
        Scaffold(
            snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
            floatingActionButton = {
                var clickCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
                ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = {
                        // show snackbar as a suspend function
                        scope.launch {
                            snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Snackbar # ${++clickCount}")
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Show snackbar")
                }
            },
            content = { innerPadding ->
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                    Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                        Text("Click to open")
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
)

I hope this is enough to help you migrating your existing code to material3.
